# Is there a significant performance difference between querying for keyword tags using keywords as fields vs. values?

Tags: azure, scalability, azure-cosmosdb

I have 4 documents:

```
[
{
    "id": "doc1",
    "keywords": [
        {
            "keyword": "keyword1",
            "weight": 1
        },
        {
            "keyword": "keyword2",
            "weight": 2
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": "doc2",
    "keywords": [
        {
            "keyword": "keyword1",
            "weight": 2
        },
        {
            "keyword": "keyword3",
            "weight": 4
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": "doc3",
    "keywords": {
        "keyword1": {
            "weight": 3
        },
        "keyword4": {
            "weight": 5
        }
    }
},
{
    "id": "doc4",
    "keywords": {
        "keyword4": {
            "weight": 1
        },
        "keyword5": {
            "weight": 2
        }
    }
}
]
```

The first two have a `"keywords"` field that is a list of dictionaries containing a keyword and a weight.  The second two have a `"keywords"` field that is a dictionary of the keywords themselves with dictionary attributes containing the weight data.

When I want to find documents that contain a particular keyword, I run this query:

```
SELECT c FROM c
JOIN
k IN c.keywords
where k.keyword="keyword1"
```

This returns all the documents among the first two documents that have the keyword "keyword1".

I can perform a similar query for the second two documents (although I may be adding unnecessary overhead with the weight check):

```
select d from d
WHERE d.keywords.keyword1.weight > 0
```

The RU cost is slightly lower for the second one, but it's only 4 documents. I will be scaling this up to around 10-20 million documents. Is one of these formats significantly more scalable than the other?

Answer (score 0):

Both approaches are scalable, but the second approach using nested properties will be better overall in terms of efficiency/RUs.